# How to create a complex query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am pretty new to hibernate was wondering if someone could help me out.  I pretty much wrote the command how I would do it in SQL I tried a couple variations none worked was wondering if someone could point out how to do such a command in hibernate.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from customer where customer_city = Harrison" 
            + " AND where customer_street = main" + " AND where customer_name = Hayes");
```

Comment: Does http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of things that could be causing problems. First, the `where` clause is duplicated after every `and`. Second, you have literal values in your HQL query, which isn't supported as far as I know. Typically, the code to execute such a query would look something like this:

```
String queryString
    = "from customer "
    + "where customer_city = ? "
    + "and customer_street = ? "
    + "and customer_name = ? ";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setString(0, "Harrison");
query.setString(1, "main");
query.setString(2, "Hayes");
List<Customer> customers = (List<Customer>) query.list();
```

Comment: I am getting a can not instantiate type Query error with this, just have to change Query query = session.createQuery(queryString); that and it worked.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Ah, yes, session.createQuery(queryString) is the right thing to do. I corrected my answer.